# Rails Ancestry summing all nodes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, recursion, ancestry

I am using [the Ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry). Each node has a numerical value associated with it (:value). Each time I CRUD a node, I want to recalculate the whole tree so that each node ends up with the sum of the values of its children. (Leaf nodes stay unchanged.)

My controller actions contain this code to trigger the recalculation:

```
def create
  ...
  @tree = Tree.new(tree_params)
  if @tree.save
    Tree.roots.each do |r|
      recalc_tree(r)        
    end
    redirect_to trees_url, notice: "Node was successfully created. " + note.to_s
  else
    render :new, notice: "There was an error saving this node. Please try again."
end
```

and in the private section at the bottom of the controller I have this custom helper method:

```
def recalc_tree(r)
    total = 0
    if r.has_children?
        r.children.each do |c|
            total = total + recalc_tree(c)
        end
        r.value = total
    else
        r.value
    end
end
```

I don't get any errors in the browser (the node saves correctly) but neither does this update any of the values of the ancestor nodes.

I tried running the helper in the console but got an "undefined method" error:

```
>> helper.recalc_tree(Tree.roots.first)

Tree Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "trees".* FROM "trees"  WHERE "trees"."ancestry" IS NULL  ORDER BY "trees"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `recalc_tree' for #<ActionView::Base:0x5fc82c0>
```

What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

The more rails-style way to do this is to use ActiveRecord's callback (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). Also since when a node is updated, only the updated node's ancestors will need to be updated, so we can save some CPU cycles by updating only ancestors along the path to the root.

Example:

```
class Tree < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :update_ancestors
  ...
  ...

  private
  def update_ancestors
    self.ancestors.each do |ancestor|
      ancestor.value = ancestor.descendants.pluck(:value).sum
      ancestor.save
    end
  end
end
```

I did not actually ran this code on my machine, but this is pretty much the direction to this problem!

Comment: Yeah! ancestor.save! If I don't save the record, it won't save. Great, thanks!

Comment: You code isn't quite right as it double counts some nodes, but I like the callback approach so will get it working soon. I also need to trigger the recalculation after_destroy.

Comment: I ended up with a "stack level too deep" error as each recalc_tree(r) requires a save for each non-leaf node, which in turn seems to trigger after_save again. So I went back to a class method instead of a callback and that works as far as I can tell.